# Spring Web - Class level RequestMapping does not work

Tags: java, spring-mvc, request-mapping

I've got a simple RestController that will serve as an API. I need every single endpoint method to
reuse a prefix to its path so I write it in a `RequestMapping` annotation at class level.
When I try to perform a GET to "/api/companies/all" it returns a 404 error:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/companies")
public class CompanyApi {
  @GetMapping("/all")
  public ResponseEntity<String> getAllCompanies() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok("all companies");
  }
}
```

However it works when the prefix is written in each method's annotation like this:

```
@RestController
public class CompanyApi {
  @GetMapping("/api/companies/all")
  public ResponseEntity<String> getAllCompanies() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok("all companies");
  }
}
```

I need to reuse the path "api/companies" but an error occurs. How do I fix this in Spring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't start with `/` in `@GetMapping` value, it will create duplicate `/`, do Instead:

```
@GetMapping("all")
```

Comment: But using `@GetMapping("/")` means the relative path to the base URL path `"/api/companies"`, right? Why `"/"` resolves to base URL path in the controller?